# ActiveX calling URL page

Tags: sql, internet-explorer, sql-server-2005, vbscript, activex

I'm using the following code inside an `ActiveX Script` job on SQl Server to call an URL every X minutes.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "iexplore.exe http://www.google.com.br"
Set WsShell = Nothing
```

it is working but the processes created keep running:
[image]

Any way of changin that code to call the URL and kill the recent called process or call it with a "time-to-live". I think it is more secure, I wouldn't want to kill the wrong process.

Comment: What is the _purpose_ of calling the URL every 'X' minutes?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the caller wants to "activate" a web page periodically - maybe the website needs to load some file into its cache in order to be guaranteed to respond rapidly to a real visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the suggestion by @Ted, you can also fetch a URL using native Microsoft capabilities in an in-process fashion. You can do this via a component known as WinHTTP ([the latest appears to be WinHTTP 5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

See my script below which includes a function to simply obtain the status of a URL. When I run this script I get the following output:

```
http://www.google.com => 200 [OK]
http://www.google.com/does_not_exist => 404 [Not Found]
http://does_not_exist.google.com => -2147012889
    [The server name or address could not be resolved]
```

If you want the actual content behind a URL, try `oHttp.ResponseText`. Here's the [WinHTTP reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are interested in other capabilities as well.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim aUrlList
aUrlList = Array( _
    "http://www.google.com", _
    "http://www.google.com/does_not_exist", _
    "http://does_not_exist.google.com" _
)

Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(aUrlList)
    WScript.Echo aUrlList(i) & " => " & GetUrlStatus(aUrlList(i))
Next

Function GetUrlStatus(sUrl)
    Dim oHttp : Set oHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    On Error Resume Next

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", SUrl, False
        .Send
    End With

    If Err Then
        GetUrlStatus = Err.Number & " [" & Err.Description & "]"
    Else
        GetUrlStatus = oHttp.Status & " [" & oHttp.StatusText & "]"
    End If

    Set oHttp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you start IE is external, you have little control over the process once it is started.
A better interactive way is like this

```
Function GetData(strUrl) 'As String
  Set web = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  web.Navigate strUrl
  Do While web.Busy
    wscript.sleep 100
  Loop
  Set doc = Nothing
  Do Until Not doc Is Nothing
    Set doc = web.Document
  Loop
  strWebPage = doc.all(1).innerHTML 'This does return the head sections
  web.Quit
  GetData = strWebPage
End Function


wscript.echo GetData("www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** As it stands now, it looks like this is not a viable solution. After multiple invocations, IE processes begin to accumulate with this approach as well. It appears this behavior has something to do with IE's session management. IE doesn't like to be abruptly terminated.

---

I found some very useful information about managing processes via WMI [here](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/processes/). Using that as a basis, I came up with the code I show below. One of the nice aspects of the WMI approach is that you are given access to the unique ID for the process. I consider my code a starting point as I'm sure further improvements are possible (including the addition of exception handling).

Perhaps others with deeper knowledge of WMI can offer additional advice.

PS: Hope you like that I wrapped this functionality inside a VBScript class called `Process`.

```vb
Option Explicit

' Const PROG = "notepad.exe"
Const TARGET = "http://www.google.com"
Dim PROG : PROG = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " & TARGET
Const ABOVE_NORMAL = 32768  ' what are the other priority constants?

Dim oProc : Set oProc = New Process
oProc.Name = PROG
' oProc.Priority = ABOVE_NORMAL
oProc.Launch

WScript.Echo "Launched '" & PROG & "' with process ID '" & oProc.ID & "'"
WScript.Sleep 5000
oProc.Terminate
WScript.Echo "Process " & oProc.ID & " killed."
Set oProc = Nothing

' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

Class Process

Public Computer
Public Name
Public Priority
Public ID
Public IsRunning

Private mHandle

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Me.Computer = "."
    Me.Name = Null
    Me.ID = -1
    Me.Priority = Null
    Me.IsRunning = False
    Set mHandle = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mHandle = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Launch()
    Dim oWmi, oStartup, oConfig
    Dim nPid

    Set oWmi = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                         & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                         & Me.Computer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set oStartup = oWmi.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

    If Not IsNull(Me.Priority) Then
        Set oConfig = oStartup.SpawnInstance_
        oConfig.PriorityClass = Me.Priority
    End If

    Set mHandle = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
    mHandle.Create Me.Name, Null, oConfig, nPid
    ' WScript.Echo "TypeName Is [" & TypeName(mHandle) & "]"
    Me.ID = nPid
    Me.IsRunning = True
End Sub

Public Sub Terminate()
    ' mHandle.Terminate  ' hmmm, doesn't work...

    Dim oWmi
    Dim colProcessList, oProc

    Set oWmi = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                                  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                                  & Me.Computer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colProcessList = oWmi.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessId = '" & Me.ID & "'")

    For Each oProc In colProcessList  ' should be only one process
        ' WScript.Echo "TypeName Is [" & TypeName(oProc) & "]"
        oProc.Terminate
    Next

    Me.IsRunning = False
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider using a lightweight command line URL retrieval program, like CURL ( http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html ) or WGET ( http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ )?  These programs can be executed from the command line quite simply:

```
wget http://www.google.com
curl http://www.google.com
```

You can execute them from VBScript like this:

```
sub shell(cmd)
    ' Run a command as if you were running from the command line
    dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    objShell.Run(cmd)
    Set objShell = Nothing
end sub

shell "wget http://www.google.com"
```

The only downside to this is that WGET and CURL won't execute javascript, download affiliated images, or render the HTML; they will simply download the web page.  In my experience, I use CURL and WGET regularly as long as I only have to retrieve a single HTML page; but if I have to render something or trigger AJAX functions I use an automatable web browser toolkit like Selenium, WATIN, or IMacros.

Comment: Good point...the question doesn't specifically indicate an interest in actually "visualizing" the content retrieved by the URL.